# Transparent legend in Bokeh

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

In Matplotlib the legend function has a keyword argument called fancybox that makes the legend slightly transparent to see the lines behind the legend. Here is an example function call:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.legend(fontsize='xx-small', loc='best', fancybox=True)
```

I can't find anything similar to this in Bokeh. Does anyone know if Bokeh has the functionality to make a plot transparent without going behind the scenes and monkey patching something in for it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by this one example in the documentation, I think you can change the legend transparency setting the `plot.legend.border_line_alpha`, which changes the transparency of the border line and also the legend itself, apparently.

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#id2

Comment: Thanks, a lot that worked. I didn't quite catch that changing the border transparency also changes the plot transparency!

Answer (score 7):

I'm using bokeh 1.0.2 and the following worked for me:

```py
# Make legend fully transparent
plot.legend.background_fill_alpha = 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

(As of Bokeh 0.9.2) Configuring the legend background was only just added a few weeks ago in a recent PR. It will be in the upcoming 0.9.3 release at the end of August 2015.

A final note, Just FYO: due to the cross-language nature of Bokeh, the capability to style the background is a feature and function of the client JS library, BokehJS. There's currently no amount of monkey patching from the python side that have any effect on making something that is not possible in BokehJS be possible. We are working on making BokehJS extensible from python, however.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep an eye out for that release! Also thanks for the note about the separation between python and BokehJS. Definitely good to know.